# C++ fstream tellg behaviour

Tags: c++, fstream

I am working on a C++ application in [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) (32-bit). When I read a file using fstream and read four bytes twice, I get confusing values from tellg. I was expecting 0, 4 and 8.

```
std::fstream file;
file.open(filename, std::ios::in , std::ios::binary);
if ( !file.is_open())
{
    throw exception("Error opening file for reading");
}
int pos = file.tellg();  // pos is 0
boost::int32_t usedBlocks;
int size = sizeof (usedBlocks);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&usedBlocks),sizeof(usedBlocks));
pos = file.tellg();      //pos is 3588
//Read reserved size
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&reservedSize),sizeof(reservedSize));
pos = file.tellg();     //pos is 3592
```

Why does this happen?

I have changed the code to use fopen, fread, and ftell, and then the pos values are 0, 4 and 8.

`usedBlocks` is a `boost::int32`. `boost::int32` is actually an `int`, not a struct. Even changing them to int gives the same result.

Comment: what is the type of reservedSize ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that overload of the `open` function.  I'm pretty sure it's not standard. Whatever the case, that's not where you put `ios::binary`.  You need to bitwise OR it together with `ios::in` in the second parameter. i.e. `file.open(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);` -- The third parameter is for something else (file protection specifications), and you should probably not even use it.

Comment: Thank you. I have put comma there by mistake.
I should have used a |

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the values of `pos` in the debugger, they may be wrong due to optimization.

Try printing the values of `pos` into the standard output.

Comment: I did look at value from debugger. Thank you for pointing it out that it can be wrong.